# MYSQL sum based on if condition from other table in left join

Tags: mysql

I am finding sum of `total` in table `customer_class_bookings` based on `IF` condition from other table `trader_job_payment`. My problem is that it is giving 0 which is wrong. Here is my code

```
select SUM(IF (trader_job_payment.status = 'DISBURSED' , customer_class_bookings.total, 0))
       AS earning from `customer_class_bookings` 
        left join `trader_job_payment` on `trader_job_payment`.`payable_id` = `customer_class_bookings`.`id` and 
        `trader_job_payment`.`payable_type` = 'Modules\\WellBeing\\Models\\CustomerClassBooking' and `trader_job_payment`.`deleted_at` = null where `trader_user_id` = 917
```

The `earning` is 0 which is wrong. Can any body help me that how to figure out this problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking for the value "null" instead of checking if the cell is NULL. Null is not a value in MySql. You have to use IS NULL function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM contacts
WHERE last_name IS NULL;
```

so your query will become (the modified part only):

```
`trader_job_payment`.`deleted_at` IS NULL
```

you can learn more about how to handle NULL [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/working-with-null.html).